# Do QUAN fields in SAP allow storing blank/null values?

Tags: abap

Does a QUAN field allow null/blank values to be stored?  Or must a number be stored in it at all times?

Not asking whether the default value can be *displayed* as blank, but whether a blank/null value can be stored in a QUAN field in a way that can be distinguished from the default value, e.g. if the default value is zero. It's stored in BCD, so it hypothetically could encode non-numeric values if SAP allows it.

Comment: Motivating example: MARC-MABST.  How would one distinguish a material/plant that should not have any stock on it (i.e. intentionally has a maximum stock level of zero) versus one that has an unspecified maximum but should be allowed to carry stock?  If a QUAN field cannot store blank/null, then it appears that this can't be distinguished with MARC-MABST.  MM02 saves the maximum stock level as zero even if it's cleared out--blank will be replaced with zero after reopening.  It's unclear whether this is a limitation of MM02 or a fundamental limitation of the data field.

Comment: if the value is exclusive, then maybe 1 (< 1 == 0)? Or if it is inclusive, what happens when a negative value is stored in that field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two completely different BCD, so maybe you are confusing them:

- [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) format used by SAP internally for ABAP packed variables (of type `P`), and which corresponds to ABAP Dictionary types `QUAN`, `CURR` or `DEC`
- [character-encoding BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCD_(character_encoding)) format.

So, the answer is no, BCD-packed fields may encode only digits 0 to 9 and sign (and the position of the decimal point is defined by its associated type).

References:

- [packed number type](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenpacked_number_type_glosry.htm)

  - *The internal representation uses the BCD format.*
- [Numeric data types > Packed Numbers](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abennumber_types.htm#@@ITOC@@ABENNUMBER_TYPES_2)

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about the character encodings going by that name--but the "BCD" SAP uses is the one I thought it was.  For example, it uses 4 bits for the sign, but the sign would only need 1 bit, so it potentially has room to store 3 more flags in that field if SAP isn't using those extra bits for something else.  But the documentation you linked certainly doesn't mention any support for blank/null values, so your answer seems true.

Comment: @lehiester that is correct, but I guess the main problem of nullable values is not about storing the nullability information but rather about doing efficient arithmetic with nullable types

Answer (score 3):

You are assuming that the concept of *nullability* exists in ABAP - it does not. In many occasions one can store such a "null value" in place by choosing an *initial value* that can be distinguished from a "non null" value (i.e. 0 if values of range [1,…) are expected). If that is not the case, an additional field is needed to store the null.

The underlying database however does have a concept of nullability and one can evaluate the [`IS NULL`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abenwhere_logexp_null.htm) predicate inside database queries, and great care must be taken when [reading nullable values from the database](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abennull_value_glosry.htm) as those are replaced with the *initial value*.

Another loosely related concept are [*unbound references*](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abendata_references.htm) - references that are not bound are somewhat a null value (thus `REF TO p` would be a semantically sound way to represent a nullable fixed point, but you probably don‘t want to spend the cost of heap allocations).